# How to install python3.8 on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: software-installation, python, python3, 21.04

I'm trying to install python3.8 on Ubuntu.
I tried a lot of command, but none of them works. I'm trying this:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev \
libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev`
```

to install the prerequisites, and I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libreadline-gplv2-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libreadline-gplv2-dev' has no installation candidate.
```

Can someone help me to install python3.8, please?

Comment: The package `libreadline-gplv2-dev` was dropped from Ubuntu after 20.04. 20.04 also includes Py3.8 already; no additional install needed. Consider installing 20.04 in a LXD Container or a Virtual Machine.

Comment: oh thank you, so if i use ubuntu 20.04 on a live usb, i've arleady pre-installed python3.8?

Comment: @CLAUDIX29 Yes, in 20.04 you would have python3.8 preinstalled, and you can also install python3.9 alongside that.